# internationalization in Node.js, Express, i18n

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization

I'm using Node.js together with Express framework and [i18n module](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node). So I use

```
var i18n = require('i18n');
app.configure(function() {
    [...]
    app.use(i18n.init);
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

in my app settings. Everything works fine, but what I really need is to force i18n to use the langauage I want. The scenario is as follows: when user is not logged in, then i18n searches for the langauage in `accept-language` header and it is ok. But when user is logged in, then I want to hold chosen langauage somewhere in user settings, retrieve it and force i18n module to use this langauage. How to do this (assuming I already know how to save/retrieve the langauge into/from db)?

Comment: just to mention [i18next - i18n for node.js](http://i18next.com/node) might be a good alternative - just have a look!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ach, sorry. I should wait a bit and inspect the i18n module. It seems that module provides to functions

```
i18n.getLocale();
```

which retrieves current language and

```
i18n.setLocale('en');
```

which sets locale as we want. The documentation really should mention this. It is important, I hope the answer helps someone. :)

Comment: hey... how did you get this to work in the end? i tried to change the locale with the command you wrote but it switches back automatically and i don't know how it works so that the setting persists.

Comment: you might have a look at http://i18next.com/node as it adds same functionality plus a lot more.

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/bdswiss/country-language if you need to know languages spoken in specific country.

Answer (score 1):

This was just released yesterday, but it sounds like it will hit the issue you are running into: [locale](https://github.com/jed/locale)